# Saving a SuperTable field within a Matrix Field

Tags: craft3, modules, plugin-supertable

I am trying to save a SuperTable field that sits within a Matrix field.

I have followed the docs as far as I can but for some reason the SuperTable data is not getting saved.

My steps are as follows:

1. Get the SuperTable field id:

```
$matrixBlocks = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle('eventPerformances')->getBlockTypeFields();
$ticketBlockId = $matrixBlocks[2]['id'];
```

2. Check that the field has content and loop over it to get the array of data:

```
if ($event['schedules'][0]['performances'][0]['tickets']) {

    $ticketsMatrix = array();
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($event['schedules'][0]['performances'] as $performance)

    {
        foreach ($performance['tickets'] as $ticket) {
            $ticketsMatrix['new'.$i] = array(
                'type' => $ticketBlockId,
                'enabled' => true,
                'fields' => array(
                    'ticketType' => $ticket['type'],
                    'minPrice' => $ticket['min_price'],
                    'maxPrice' => $ticket['max_price'],
                    'currency' => $ticket['currency'],
                ),
            );
            $i++;
        }
    }
} else {

    $ticketsMatrix = '';
}
```

3. Pass this array through when saving the parent Matrix field

```
$performancesMatrix = array();
$performances = $event['schedules'][0]['performances'];

$i = 1;

foreach ($performances as $performance) {

    $performancesMatrix['new'.$i] = array(
        'type' => 'performance',
        'enabled' => true,
        'fields' => array(
            'performanceDate' => date_create($performance['ts']),
            'duration' => $performance['duration'] / 60,
            'tickets' => $ticketsMatrix
        ),
    );
    $i++;
}
```

The `performanceDate` and `duration` fields get saved as expected but the `$ticketsMatrix` data is not saving in the nested SuperTable field.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out, I had to delve into the matrix field and get the individual block ids for the Supertable fields.

```
$matrixBlocks = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle('eventPerformances')->getBlockTypeFields();
$ticketBlockId = (int)$matrixBlocks[2]['id'];
$linkBlockId = (int)$matrixBlocks[3]['id'];

$ticketsField = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldById($ticketBlockId);
$ticketsBlockTypes = SuperTable::$plugin->getService()->getBlockTypesByFieldId($ticketsField->id);
$ticketsBlockType = $ticketsBlockTypes[0];

$linksField = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldById($linkBlockId);
$linkBlockTypes = SuperTable::$plugin->getService()->getBlockTypesByFieldId($linksField->id);
$linksBlockType = $linkBlockTypes[0];
```

After casting these to integers and then using that value as the `type` value when saving the matrix block, it all works!

Full code below, hopefully it will help others out in this situation:

```
$matrixBlocks = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle('eventPerformances')->getBlockTypeFields();
$ticketBlockId = (int)$matrixBlocks[2]['id'];
$linkBlockId = (int)$matrixBlocks[3]['id'];

$ticketsField = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldById($ticketBlockId);
$ticketsBlockTypes = SuperTable::$plugin->getService()->getBlockTypesByFieldId($ticketsField->id);
$ticketsBlockType = $ticketsBlockTypes[0];

$linksField = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldById($linkBlockId);
$linkBlockTypes = SuperTable::$plugin->getService()->getBlockTypesByFieldId($linksField->id);
$linksBlockType = $linkBlockTypes[0];

$performancesMatrix = array();
$ticketsMatrix = array();
$linksMatrix = array();
$performances = $event['schedules'][0]['performances'];
$i = 1;

foreach ($performances as $performance) {

     if (array_key_exists('tickets', $performance))
     {
         $t = 1;

         foreach ($performance['tickets'] as $ticket) 
         {

             $ticketsMatrix['new'.$t] = array(
                 'type' => $ticketsBlockType->id,
                 'enabled' => true,
                 'fields' => array(
                 'ticketType' => $ticket['type'],
                 'minPrice' => (array_key_exists('min_price', $ticket) ? $ticket['min_price'] : ''),
                 'maxPrice' => (array_key_exists('max_price', $ticket) ? $ticket['max_price'] : ''),
                 'currency' => (array_key_exists('currency', $ticket) ? $ticket['currency'] : ''),
                 ),
             );
             $t++;
         }
     }

    if(array_key_exists('links', $performance))
    {
         $l = 1;
         foreach($performance['links'] as $link) 
         {

             $linksMatrix['new'.$l] = array(
                 'type' => $linksBlockType->id,
                 'enabled' => true,
                 'fields' => array(
                     'linkType' => (array_key_exists('type', $link) ? $link['type'] : ''),
                     'linkUrl' => (array_key_exists('url', $link) ? $link['url'] : ''),
                 ),
             );
             $l++;
         }
     }

     $performancesMatrix['new'.$i] = array(
         'type' => 'performance',
         'enabled' => true,
         'fields' => array(
             'performanceDate' => date_create($performance['ts']),
             'duration' => (array_key_exists('duration', $performance) ? $performance['duration'] / 60 : ''),
             'tickets' => $ticketsMatrix,
              'performanceLinks' => $linksMatrix
         ),
     );
     $i++;
 }

$entry->setFieldValue('eventPerformances', $performancesMatrix);
```